# I wander if by using ngx.shared.dict, is there any occassion that makes my data overwrite before it can be inserted into mysql?

Tags: nginx, lua

I am using ngx lua module, but recently, I need my ngx.shared.dict record and insert some file meta into mysql , but when I do that, I keep thinking what if many people visit this uri at same time, is it possible the data changed before it is inserted into database?

Comment: Your question seems a bit vague, would you mind giving an example of what you mean?